# Pass Data to Fragment from Activity, when intially loaded with Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So my issue is basically my MainActivity is initially loaded with a Fragment, which we will call MyFragment.

I am loading JSON, from online and wanting to pass into my MyFragment.

The problem is arising when setContentView is called in the MainActivity, it is calling onCreateView in MyFragment, which contains **getArguments.getSerializable("myTag")**. The key isn't passed because I haven't loaded the JSON yet.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

In my MyFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(getArguments() != null) {
            coll = (HashSet<String>) getArguments().getSerializable("myTag");
        }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
}
```

MainActivity (assume I loaded my JSON already):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadJSON();
    passTagsToFragment(); //passes to the fragment
}

public void passTagsToFragment(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("myTags", tagsSet);
    TagsFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

EDIT:

Basically, my issue is that I want to load the MainActivity fully, before even starting to load the Fragment. Not sure how to do that.

EDIT 2:

I fixed the problem here is my code: (Changed the variable names)

MainActivity.java

```
public TagsFragment passInfoToTagsFramgent(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("tags", tagsList);
    TagsFragment frag = new TagsFragment();
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return frag;
}
```

in OnPostExecute of MainActvity.java:

```
Fragment tagFragment = passInfoToTagsFramgent();
                FragmentTransaction transaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, tagFragment);
                transaction.commit();
```

Comment: call it inside onActivityCreated() method

Comment: @SavaDimitrijević got the same error

Comment: you can either call the API to fetch JSON from the server in the fragment or you can use a blocking progress dialog until JSON retrieved from the server and then load the fragment using the data.

Answer (score 0):

loadJSON is from online source, so I assume it is an AsyncTask.

I usually do this as a lamda expression (kotlin):

```
loadJSON({passTagsToFragment()})
```

loadJSON should take a lamda expression as parameter:

```
loadJSON(private val callback:()->Unit )
```

and in the AsyncTask::onPostExecute, you should call the callback:

```
callback.invoke()
```

or just

```
callback()
```

Then you made sure the fragment is opened when the JSON is loaded and passed to fragment.

OK let me try to make it in Java.

In your AsyncTask which loads JSON, you will need an interface e.g.,

```
public interface JSONLoadCallback {
    void loaded();
}
```

And the its constructor takes the interface as parameter:

```
class JSONLoader : AsyncTask<....> {
    JSONLoader(JSONLoadCallback callback) {
        _callback = callback;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        _callback.loaded();
    }
}
```

And your Activity implements JSONLoadCallback:

```
@Override
public void loaded() {
    passTagsToFragment();
}
```

And should pass itself to the AsyncTask:

```
JSONLoader(this).executeOnExecutor();
```

This way, the loaded() function is fired when JSON load is finished.

You see, Java codes are very verbal, Kotlin almost removed the necessity of Java interface.

Comment: Thanks, however, don't understand your code. I am running AyncTask, can you translate it to Java for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your **passTagsToFragment()** method in post execute method of your asynctask when all json data gets loaded.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     passTagsToFragment();
 }
```

Comment: Same error. In my XML, I have added a fragment view. So when I first start up my application it loads the Fragment.java before the MainActivity.java. Maybe this will help clear things up.

Comment: could you please share the code of activity_main.xml & its java class

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can call Loadjson() method on fragment as well and use data accordingly but if you have some specific logic you can use asynctask and on json retrieval with progress bar you can set any MyFragment callback and update your fragment accordingly.